# C++ Global mapping for mongo database fields

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, singleton

I have an application that uses mongodb as the back end database and wanted a way to centralize the field names used within a mongo collection for access on the C++ side of things. The field names are used in various parts of the application (serialization, querying, etc...) and I would prefer not to actual hard code the field names in all of these different locations to ease with maintenance.

Using a singleton initially came to mind, but I would prefer not to use one. I also toyed with the idea of using boost fusion to create a mapping of types to field names, but the types would all be essentially empty structs. Thoughts on an approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use an enum with serialization/deserialization - one enum per collection would make sense:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

template<typename def, typename inner = typename def::type>
class safe_enum : public def
{
    inner val;

public:
    typedef typename def::type type;
    safe_enum(type v) : val(v) {}
    inner underlying() const { return val; }

    friend bool operator == (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val == rhs.val; }
    friend bool operator != (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val != rhs.val; }
    friend bool operator < (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val < rhs.val; }
    friend bool operator <= (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val <= rhs.val; }
    friend bool operator > (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val > rhs.val; }
    friend bool operator >= (const safe_enum & lhs, const safe_enum & rhs) { return lhs.val >= rhs.val; }
};

class some_collection_fields_def
{
public:
    enum type { invalid, somename, anothername, morenames };
};

class some_collection_fields
    :
        public safe_enum< some_collection_fields_def >
{
public:
    typedef safe_enum< some_collection_fields_def > BaseType;
public:
    some_collection_fields( type v )
        :
            BaseType( v )
    {}
    some_collection_fields( const std::string& v )
        :
            BaseType( invalid )
    {
        *(this) = v;
    }
    some_collection_fields& operator =( const std::string& in )
    {
        string_bimap_type::right_map::const_iterator cit = string_bimap.right.find( in );
        if ( cit == string_bimap.right.end() )
        {
            throw std::domain_error( std::string( __func__ ) + ": Failed to convert from [" + in + "]" );
        }
        (*this) = cit->second;
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& as_string() const
    {
        string_bimap_type::left_map::const_iterator cit = string_bimap.left.find( this->underlying() );
        if ( cit == string_bimap.left.end() )
        {
            throw std::range_error( std::string( __func__ ) + ": Undefined value [" + std::to_string( this->underlying() ) + "]" );
        }
        return cit->second;
    }
private:
    typedef boost::bimap< type, std::string > string_bimap_type;
    static string_bimap_type string_bimap_init()
    {
        string_bimap_type tmp_string_bimap;
        tmp_string_bimap.insert( string_bimap_type::value_type( somename, "somename" ) );
        tmp_string_bimap.insert( string_bimap_type::value_type( anothername, "anothername" ) );
        tmp_string_bimap.insert( string_bimap_type::value_type( morenames, "morenames" ) );
        return tmp_string_bimap;
    }
    static string_bimap_type string_bimap;
};

some_collection_fields::string_bimap_type some_collection_fields::string_bimap = some_collection_fields::string_bimap_init();

std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& out, const some_collection_fields& in )
{
    out << in.as_string();
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    {
        some_collection_fields field = some_collection_fields::somename;
        std::cout << field << std::endl;
        std::cout << field.as_string() << std::endl;
        std::cout << field.underlying() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        some_collection_fields field( "anothername" );
        std::cout << field << std::endl;
        std::cout << field.as_string() << std::endl;
        std::cout << field.underlying() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o 17687554.a1 17687554.a1.cpp
```

output:

```
$ ./17687554.a1 
somename
somename
1
anothername
anothername
2
```

Notes:

1. safe_enum from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Safe_Enum)
2. you could probably generalize this with a template

Answer (score 0):

I kept with an approach using boost fusion and enumerations.

```
enum ActivitySchemaEnum
{
  DEFINITION,
  NAME,
  STATE,
  START,
  END
};

template <ActivitySchemaEnum ACTSCHEMA_V>
struct Field;

typedef boost::fusion::map<
  boost::fusion::pair<Field<DEFINITION>, char const*>,
  boost::fusion::pair<Field<NAME>, char const*>,
  boost::fusion::pair<Field<STATE>, char const*>,
  boost::fusion::pair<Field<START>, char const*>,
  boost::fusion::pair<Field<END>,   char const*>
> actinst_schema;

actinst_schema const ActivitySchema(
  boost::fusion::make_pair<Field<DEFINITION> >("definition"),
  boost::fusion::make_pair<Field<NAME> >("name"),
  boost::fusion::make_pair<Field<STATE> >("state"),
  boost::fusion::make_pair<Field<START> >("start"),
  boost::fusion::make_pair<Field<END> >("end")
);
```

Then in client code I make calls like (simple call, but you get the idea.)

```
const char* myFieldName = boost::fusion::at_key<Field<DEFINITION> >(ActivitySchema);
```

Client usage is a little bit verbose, but I think it's actually pretty self describing with what you are doing.